# Does "chmod -R 700 directory_1" update directories pointed by softlinks?

Tags: permissions, chmod, recursive

Does "`chmod -R 700 directory_1`" update directories under softlinks? Forexample, there is a softlink under `directory_1` folder: "`my_softlink`". And `my_softlink` points to a `directory_2`.

Will permissions of directory_2's and files under it be updated to 700 when I do "`chmod -R 700 directory_1`"

Best Regards

Comment: Seems like you could just try it and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> chmod  never  changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.  However, for each symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of  the  pointed-to  file.   **In contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals.**

So the answer is, no, it will not change anything for `directory_2`.